# How to replace or convert a SQLite column string value with another string value?

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a SQLite query where I have a column that contains very long string values in each row. The string presents different pieces of transaction data I.E. transaction amount, transaction state (completed/cancelled), users who completed the transactions, etc.

Right now I am only interested in querying these columns to show me which transactions were COMPLETED, that is, the row's string contains "state":"COMPLETED". This value is preceded and proceeded by other string data as stated above. For instance, randomddata randomdata randomdata randomdata "state":"COMPLETED" randomdata randomdata randomdata. Instead of querying the column to show this entire string value, I want to the query to produce/convert this string as COMPLETED.

I've looked into the REPLACE function and TRIM function, but it seems like for both of those I need specific characters or values to be replaced. I can't do that because the "randomdata" values are different for every cell in this specific column. I'm able to filter out the rows with "COMPLETED" in them using the LIKE function, but haven't figured out any conversions.

I'd really appreciate anyone's assistance here because I feel like I'm dead in the water :D.

Comment: Could you provide with an example of what your data looks like and what result do you need to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to replace or trim the column values.
If all you need is to query the table then use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN columnname LIKE '%COMPLETED%' THEN 'COMPLETED' END AS aliasname,
       <other columns>  
FROM tablename
```

Replace `columnname` with th ecolumn's name and `aliasname` with the alias of the column.

If you want only the rows that contain `'COMPLETED'`, set the condition in the `WHERE` clause and return a column with the value `'COMPLETED'`:

```
SELECT 'COMPLETED' AS aliasname,
       <other columns>  
FROM tablename
WHERE columnname LIKE '%COMPLETED%'
```